# Understanding the notation $\nabla$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, fluid-dynamics

I came across this problem when going over some material related to shear stress vector.

As far as I know the symbol $\nabla$ has a couple of different meanings.

Let $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$ be the unit normal vectors in the $x,y$ and $z$ directions.

**Gradient:**

When applied to a scalar field $u(x,y,z)$ it gives a vector: that is

$$\nabla u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\vec{i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\vec{j}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\vec{k}$$

**Divergence:**

When applied to a vector $\vec{u}=u\vec{i}+v\vec{j}+w\vec{k}$:

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{u}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$$

**Curl:**
Again applied for the $\vec{u}=u\vec{i}+v\vec{j}+w\vec{k}$
$$\nabla\times\vec{u}=
\begin{vmatrix}
 \vec{i}&\vec{j}  &\vec{k}\\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}&\frac{\partial }{\partial y}  & \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
 u&v  &w  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

However, for the statement (obtained from: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250227/)):
$$\vec{u}=u_x\vec{i}_x+u_y\vec{i}_y+u_z\vec{i}_z$$ with $\vec{n}=\vec{i}_y$

I cannot understand why:

$$(\vec{\nabla}\vec{u})^T\cdot \vec{n}=\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\vec{i_y}$$

Can someone please explain this to me.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Did you mean $u_y$ rather than $v_y$?

Comment: Do you understand that $\vec\nabla\vec u$ is a tensor? Do you know how to write it using index notation?

Comment: I think that result is incorrect. I get $\partial\vec u/ \partial y$.

Comment: It must be $~(\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{u})~$  a scalar , those you obtain scalar time vector, this make sense. This $~(\vec{\nabla}\vec{u})^T~$ is  not correct, a scalar transpose ?

Comment: The result looks incorrect to me as well. Where did you see it? Some additional context could be very helpful in understanding what the author was thinking.

Comment: @Eli the transpose is not a problem. The notation inside the brackets is not a divergence, it is the gradient of a vector, which yields a tensor (a.k.a. a matrix) which can indeed be transposed.

Comment: @E.P. I got this from : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250227/wall-shear-stress..   
So did you mean that the result inside the brackets is the curl of the vector $u$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\nabla \vec{u}\right)^T = \partial_i u_j \vec{e}_i \otimes \vec{e}_j=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial u_x /\partial x \quad \partial u_y /\partial x \quad \partial u_z /\partial x \\
\partial u_x /\partial y \quad \partial u_y /\partial y \quad \partial u_z /\partial y \\
\partial u_x /\partial z \quad \partial u_y /\partial z \quad \partial u_z /\partial z \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(in the middle the $e_i$ are the unit vectors, summation convention used)

Comment: As I have mentioned in other answers/comments it is advised to use $(\nabla u)_{ij}=\nabla _j u_i$ instead of $\nabla _i u_j$.

Comment: You're right, I've transposed it. Had it in my head the other way round but checked with Marsden&Hughes and Noll&Truessdell to confirm your comment. Thanks.